# Safari Push Package: how to fix Apple's expired WWDR certificate

Tags: c#, cryptography, apple-push-notifications, pkcs#7

Well, we all knew that, that was about to happen, the Apple WWDR certificate has expired on Valentine's Day (that's what I call "developer love") according to the [news release](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/)  from Apple.

I'm using C# to generate a Push Package for Safari, and, *surprise*, this does not work any-more. This is the message that I get in my logging endpoint instead:

> {"logs":["Signature verification of push package failed"]}

This is how my old PKCS#7 Signing code looked like:

```
//  Sign the message with the private key of the signer.
static byte[] PKCS7SignMessage(byte[] message, X509Certificate2 signerCertificate)
{
    //  Place message in a ContentInfo object.
    //  This is required to build a SignedCms object.
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(message);

    //  Instantiate SignedCms object with the ContentInfo above.
    //  Has default SubjectIdentifierType IssuerAndSerialNumber.
    //  Has default Detached property value false, so message is
    //  included in the encoded SignedCms.
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

    //  Formulate a CmsSigner object for the signer.
    CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCertificate);
    cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;        

    //  Sign the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

    //  Encode the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
    return signedCms.Encode();
}
```

Apple asks to also "pass the path to the renewed intermediate for the extra certificates parameter".

So I tried this:

```
X509Certificate2 appleIntermediate = new X509Certificate2();
appleIntermediate.Import(@"Path-to-new-WWRD.cer");
cmsSigner.Certificates.Add(appleIntermediate);
```

**It didn't work.**  (Signature verification of push package failed)

Later I tried to change this line:

```
cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
```

**It didn't work.** I've got an exception saying:

> "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority".

All right, now I decided to:

- Add All of Apple CA root certificates to the local machine's trusted certificate store.
- Add the renewed WWRD certificate to the local machine's intermediate certificate store.
- Restart the process and try the code again. Good news, it is now signing again including, in theory, the whole certificate chain.

**BUT: It didn't work.** (Signature verification of push package failed)

According to Apple, fixing this this is piece of cake:

> **Safari Push Notifications**
>
> Update your notification package signing server to include your web push certificate and the renewed intermediate certificate by February 14, 2016. After this date, new users will not be able to sign up for push notifications from your website until your server has been updated. If you were using the openssl_pkcs7_sign function to sign your push package with only your web push certificate, you should pass the path to the renewed intermediate for the extra certificates parameter.

Now, what does that mean in plan English?
And how can I apply that to a C# context?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @JonSquared not yet. I decided no to give this a huge priority giving that Safari does not have a huge market share. As long as Firefox and Chrome keep offering me good Push message support, I can say the f* word to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not want the whole chain. They only expect your certificate, and their intermediate certificate to be included. So your code should look something like this:

```
    static public byte[] PKCS7SignMessage(byte[] manifest_data, X509Certificate2 signerCertificate) {
        X509Certificate2Collection ca_chain;
        ContentInfo content;
        SignedCms signed_cms;
        CmsSigner signer;

        signed_cms = new SignedCms();

        ca_chain = new X509Certificate2Collection(new X509Certificate2(@"Path-to-new-intermediate-WWRD.cer"));

        content = new ContentInfo(manifest_data);

        signed_cms = new SignedCms(content, true);

        signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, signerCertificate);
        signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot;
        signer.Certificates.AddRange(ca_chain);

        signed_cms.ComputeSignature(signer);

        return signed_cms.Encode();
    }
```